# how to save a list in windows phone 8

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, save, isolatedstorage

I am beginner in this so I do not know much.  So I am making an app where the user adds a checkbox(es) to a stack panel and looks something like this:

```
        CheckBox CheckBox = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox.Content = TextBox1.Text;
        StackPanel1.Children.Add(CheckBox);
        TextBox1.Text = "";
```

Then in the Application Bar i want user to be able to save their list in Isolated Storage and then close the app and then comeback and be able to open up a popup or a page that will display all their saved lists and when the press on them, it will open up their list.  Much like in Microsoft word on PC where you can press open and it will display a folder containing all your documents.

I would really appreciate a DETAILED explanation as I am just a teen.
Thank You

Comment: Did my post help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link has some really great videos. I started off on using them. There is one video which does pretty much exactly what you want, I think it's at the bottom of page 4, and the continuation on page 5, but can't quite remember.

But you should check several of them out, there really great.

[Channel 9 - Windows phone for beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners?page=1)

I would also suggest you looking at this website which contains nice clear info about IsolatedStorage: [All about IsolatedStorage](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files)

In fact the [GeekChamp](http://geekchamp.com) website is really good for finding out how to do things after you've started understanding more about Windows Phone and C#